# RuntimeError (Failed to execute: Error: "\xFE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

Trying to use Wicked PDF.

I have this code in the controller

```
  def pdf
  pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  render_to_string(
  pdf: 'filename.pdf',
  template: '/pages/poa.html.slim',
  layout: '/layouts/pdf'),
  header: {
      content: render_to_string({
          template: '/pdfs/poa_header.html.slim',
          layout: '/layouts/pdf'
      })
  })

   save_path = [Rails.root, '/public/pdf/', 'filename.pdf'].join
   File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file | file << pdf
   end
   end
```

I am getting this error message when trying to execute the action above

```
RuntimeError (Failed to execute:

Error: "\xFE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8):
```

I already tried to empty the content of templates and layout I am rendering but still got the error.

Answer (score 16):

This can happen if you try to write to a file that is not in binary mode.

Either open the file with the 'b' flag `File.open(file_path, 'wb')`, or if you already have a file handle, you can switch it to binary mode before writing:

```
f = Tempfile.open(%w(my .pdf))
f.binmode
f << pdf
f.close
```

Comment: Appreciate you showing both the methods for adding this on `File` and `Tempfile` objects.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this issue myself. Strangely, it was only happening when I was running under Rails 4.rc2 (worked fine under Rails 3.2.13). I got around it by forcing the resulting pdf string encoding to UTF-8.

So in your example, try something like this:

```
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file | file << pdf.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

While the above line fixed things for me, I found out the underlying issue was actually some gems that were downgraded during the process of upgrading to Rails 4.rc2. After forcing some dependencies to get later gem versions, I can now run without the #force_encoding as I did before with rails 3.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Could you tell me which gems you updated to get rid of this??

Comment: I wish I could, but there were so many gems involved I didn't track it down to a single one. I would recommend looking for very outdated gems (bundle outdated) and start with those.

Comment: ok, thanks! Its strange since it's a new project and using rails 4.0.... I'll take a look and post them here if I find out which one is it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error using WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string.

try removing:

WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string

so it reads:

pdf = render_from_string( pdf: ....

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method 'render_from_string' for #<EventsController:0x007ff084c0fae0>` - any idea?

Comment: @sergserg You can only use that method in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is from special characters that are appearing somewhere in your template code, (e.g. curly quotes that come from pasting from MS-Word).  I use this bit of code to find exactly where its happening:

```
body = File.read('raw.txt')
puts body.encode('ASCII-8BIT', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)
```